# Generate "Event" function array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-plugins

I write my first jquery plugin (calendar). Now it works all fine but I have imbedded the events inside in my plugin like:

```
var days = [
    new Event('9-5', 'test1', 1),
    new Event('9-7', 'test2', 8),
    new Event('9-8', 'test3', 2)       
];
```

Now I submit the events "days" to my plugin from outside with:

```
var days = [
    ['9-5','test1', 1],
    ['9-7', 'test2', 8],
    ['9-8', 'test3', 2]      
];
$("#cal").calendar( { year: "2015", month: "9", events: days } );
```

and in the plugin with

```
var config = {
// default settings
    year: "2015",
    month: "9",
    events: ""
// ...
};
// change default settings
if (settings) { config = $.extend( {}, config, settings ); }
```

And now my problem I try to generate the same event array dynamicly with:

```
var days = [];
config.events.each(function( index ) {
    days.push(new Event(config.events[index][0],config.events[index][1],config.events[index][2]));
});
```

but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: config.events.each is not a function
```

Here is my Event function:

```
function Event(start,title, duration){ 

    if(start instanceof Date){
        this.start = start;   
    }
    this.title = title;
    this.dur = duration;
    this.end= new Date(this.start);
    ....
}
```

How to do that right?
Thanks a lot

**Edit**

I have used the each function not right:

```
 config.events.each(function( index ) {
```

has to be:

```
 $.each(config.events, function( index ) {
```

Comment: `config.events.forEach(...)` error message `TypeError: config.events.each is not a function` is quite explicit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using .each correctly. $.each() takes two arguments. The first is the array/object and the second is the callback function. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/